# How to compare float values from a complex object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to compare the Float values and return the validation error based on that.

My current implementation is like below.

```
var items= myitems.ToLookup(model=> (model.Id)
            .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Select(myobject => new Tuple<int, float>(myobject.PId, myobject.VersionId)).Distinct().Count() > 1);

if(items != null)
 {
 //Validation Message
 }
```

But what I need is that, List object may contain more than 2 items also some times in which if the version id can be like 1.00, 1.01, 1.02 But if the list contains 1.0,2.1,3.0 as version Id's it should throw the validation message.
To be precise, It can contain the minor versions but there should not be a major version at all with the same PID.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Don't store versions as float. Use the [`Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) class instead

Comment: Truncate the fractional part of the float before doing your comparison.  Or cast to an int.

Comment: @Cid Thanks for the suggestion, down the line will change or will take care but the current structure is created back 7 years before.

Comment: There is at least one major version difference if `.Max() - .Min() >= 1`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert but the problem is that list is not only having two items, It may contain n number of items.

Comment: ...and? `Max` and `Min` operate on lists of arbitrary length. You may need to group by `PId` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as suggested by Jeroen,

```
bool isduplicated = false;           
var duplicates = duplicateItems.Select(x => x.VersionId).OrderByDescending(x=>x).ToList();
  if(duplicates.Count >= 2)
    {
     var duplicated = duplicates.Max() - duplicates.Min();
       if(duplicated >= 1)
          {
            isduplicated = true;
          }
    }
```